# AviFile Library creates avi bigger than 2 GB- not useable

Tags: c#, compression, avi

I am using the AviFile Library to make a avi video from Bitmaps, comming from Kinect. The file size gets really high, and over 2 GB I cannot open these files anymore. I will have to compress these files. Does anyone know a tool how I can compress it or a better lib than AviFile?

Kind regards

Alexander Ziegler

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I am having a NTFS file system. Files under 2 GB work (I guess 2 GB because a file with 1,98 worked, 2,03 didn't). Did you work with the AviFile lib?

Comment: One possible explanation is that the library use 32-bit signed integer for the file size, so things blow up when the size is over 2GB.

Comment: I found an intersting hint in the discussion: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library?msg=3235192#xx3235192xx (Take a look to "It can't read above 2GB.[Avifil32.dll] limitation?" ) I think there might be the solution. I will follow this thread and give feedback later

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks this sounds logic

Comment: http://neuron2.net/LVG/filesize.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have done a work around! The biggest problem was to handle the huge amount of images comming from the kinect. With compressing it was not possible to write them to file (--> out of memory). So I write them just into a file (during recording) as bytes. After recording I read them out, compress them and save them to avi (the files getting much smaller about 100 MB). Thanks for every comment